# Training an Image Captioning Model with variable number of captions per image

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language, computer-vision

I am following [this guide](https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_captioning/) for training an Image Captioning model

It uses a dataset which always has 5 captions per image. My dataset greatly varies how many captions I have per image from 1-42. This is giving me errors when using the above code, because my data is not rectangular.

I had thought to rearrange the data so there is only ever 1 caption per image and then just have images duplicated up to 42 times in the dataset. Would there be any drawbacks to this approach?

Are there any better approaches?